# Alfresco X-Frame options

Tags: php, iframe, alfresco-share, x-frame-options

i'm triying to display an iframe with alfresco, but is giving me error

> refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

i follow this tutorial: [Alfresco Iframe](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/ewinlof/2013/03/12/introducing-the-iframepolicy-in-alfresco-share/)

i modified the share-security-config.xml, triying

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="SecurityHeadersPolicy">
  <headers>         
     <header>
        <name>X-Frame-Options</name>
        <enabled>false</enabled>            
     </header>
  </headers>
```

and this

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="IFramePolicy" replace="true">
    <same-domain>allow</same-domain>
    <cross-domain>      
        <url>http://mytrustdomain.com/</url>
    </cross-domain>
</config>
```

But still is giving me the same error, can be that Alfresco is not refreshing the config file or what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Always you modify some file from Alfresco, you need restart the server, stoping the tomcat service and starting again.

If tomcat is not stopped, you will not see the changes, the fast solution, reset the server, the another solution is:

Windows: `tasklist` get the PID and then `TASKKILL /f /PID x`

Linux: `ps -ef | grep tomcat` then `kill -9 PID`